# update table based on another tables (4 tables) value at mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 4 tables

First table : customer (its record about 2000's)

```
ID      province      regency     district
1       CJ            SE          T district
2       CJ            SE          G district
3       CJ            SE          B district
.....
```

Second table : province

```
ID      province      province_id
1       CJ            33        
2       WJ            32         
3       EJ            31         
.....
```

Third table : regency

```
ID      regency        province_id
3301    SE city        33        
3302    SE regency     33         
3303    SK city        33         
3304    SK regency     33         
.....
```

Fourth table : district

```
ID      district       regency_id
3301    T district     3301        
3302    G district     3301         
3303    A district     3302         
3304    B district     3302         
.....
```

I'd like to update customer at regency so result is being like below. I've already use `update` with `inner join` and so on but there's no result as I need.

```
ID      province      regency      district
1       CJ            SE city      T district
2       CJ            SE city      G district
3       CJ            SE regency   B district
.....
```

I've used this query but it doesn't work at all. The result is nothing

```
UPDATE customer
inner JOIN province ON customer.province = province.`name` 
inner join district on customer.district = district.`name`
SET customer.regency = regencie.`name` 
WHERE
    customer.regency = province.`name` 
    AND customer.district = district.`name`
```

Thank you very much. Correct me if there was post with similar problem which solved already.

Comment: What have you ever tried?

Comment: Fix your data structure.  One of the principles of normalization is that data is stored in only one place.  So, don't store the regency at the customer level; look it up when you need it.

Comment: @D-Shih i added the query i used before

Comment: It is hard to spot errors in your query when you mix different languages and use different table/field names in your explanation and actual code.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but what i need is store it into customer :D cause there'll be error on my php structure if don't change the customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update with `JOIN`,You can try this.

> UPDATE [table]
>
> JOIN [table] ...
>
> SET [col] = [col1]
>
> Where ...

```
UPDATE customer c 
inner join province p on p.province = c.province
inner join regency r on r.province_id = p.province_id
SET c.regency = r.regency
```

*SQLFIDDLE:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b0cb6/1*

**EDIT**

From your comment you need to `join` on `district` table link by

like this.

```
UPDATE customer c 
inner join province p on p.province = c.province
inner join regency r on r.province_id = p.province_id
inner join district d on d.regency_id = r.ID
SET c.regency = r.regency
where c.district = d.district
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5dc7b2/1*

Comment: actually it works but that query make the customer with ID 3 has regency value "SE city", i make an alias from real data, those data isn't real

Comment: 'cause based on the district table that B district is in SE regency, not in SE city